# What are the most known database disk storage layout algorithms?

Tags: ds.data-structures, big-list, db.databases

I can list for example algorithms used in databases:

- append only b-trees (MVCC like used in CouchDB)
- merged logs (like used in Big Table, Hbase, Cassandra)
- paged storages grouped in extents (like in InnoDB engine of MySQL)
- fractal trees (like used in TokuDB engine of MySQL)

Are there any others? similar or totaly different?

Answer (score 6):

The Fractal Trees I have seen overviewed in Tokutek talks are [Cache-Oblivious Lookahead Arrays](http://supertech.csail.mit.edu/papers/sbtree.pdf) (COLAs), which are at the intersection of two motivating storage layout ideas. If you're looking for similar layouts, you might be interested in them:

1. Decreasing insertion time at the cost of increased search time. See [Buffered Repository Trees](http://www.daimi.au.dk/~large/ioS06/BGVW.pdf) and [$B^{\epsilon}$ trees](http://cs.au.dk/~gerth/pub/soda03.html).
2. [Cache-oblivious data structures](http://www.cs.au.dk/~gerth/pub/cacheoblivious05.html).

The COLAs paper discusses another data structure at this intersection, as does [a more recent improvement](http://www.cs.au.dk/~gerth/pub/soda10.html).

Implementation-wise, I only know of one other DBMS that uses cache-oblivious data structures: [EaseDB](http://www.cse.ust.hk/cactus/), which is in-memory and appears to no longer be under active development.

Answer (score 4):

Columnar stores. There are some great papers on the topic from the c-store project: http://db.lcs.mit.edu/projects/cstore/

The most interesting thing about columnar stores is that many operations can be performed directly on compressed data.

Answer (score 3):

Append only again but with concurrency friendly caching by RethinkDB. http://www.rethinkdb.com/papers/rrcache.pdf

--Sai

Answer (score 1):

There is a distinction between LSM-Tree and Log-Structured Storage:

- [Log-Structured Merge Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-structured_merge-tree) (LevelDB, SQLite4, Apache Cassandra, and others).
- [Log-Structured Storage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_DB) (Berkeley DB Java Edition)